# Hit to Database in loop php

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I am very new to PHP. I am just creating a simple page that fetch the data from database and generate the XML. There are two tables one having the competitor table and second has ranking for these competitors, So i am able to fetch the candidate data and when i am looping to this data and try to hit to DB again in the loop, getting following Error:

> Undefined variable: mysqli in
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in

I have tried few things but that didn't work. here is my code:

```
<?php
/** create XML file */ 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "******", "****");
/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
   echo "Connect failed ".$mysqli->connect_error;
   exit();
}else{
}
$query = "select * from competitors where eventid=290 order by 1 desc LIMIT 0, 10;";
$booksArray = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
/* fetch associative array */
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   array_push($booksArray, $row);
  }
   if(count($booksArray)){
createXMLfile($booksArray);

 }
/* free result set */
   $result->free();
}
function createXMLfile($booksArray){
   $filePath = 'book.xml';
   $dom     = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
   $root      = $dom->createElement('books'); 
   for($i=0; $i<count($booksArray); $i++){
$eventid        =  $booksArray[$i]['eventid'];  
 $fee      =  $booksArray[$i]['fee']; 
$competitorid_system    =  $booksArray[$i]['competitorid'];
$datetimeentered     =  $booksArray[$i]['datemodified']; 
// $bookISBN      =  $booksArray[$i]['ISBN']; 
//  $bookCategory  =  $booksArray[$i]['category'];  
$book = $dom->createElement('book');
 $book->setAttribute('eventid', $eventid);
$name     = $dom->createElement('fee', $fee); 
$book->appendChild($name); 
$author   = $dom->createElement('competitorid_system', $competitorid_system); 

 $book->appendChild($author); 

 $price    = $dom->createElement('datetimeentered', $datetimeentered); 

$book->appendChild($price); 

// fetch other data
$query = "select * from ranking where eventid=290 and competitorid=".$competitorid_system;;

 echo "Query".$query;
   //exit();
$booksRankingArray = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
array_push($booksRankingArray, $row);
}
if(count($booksRankingArray)){
createXMLfile($booksRankingArray);
 }
/* free result set */
$result->free();
}
$root->appendChild($book);
}
$dom->appendChild($root); 
$dom->save($filePath); 
} 
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. It's very hard to read and follow the code when the indentations are totally random like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$mysqli` variable is out out of scope for `createXMLfile()`.

> The scope of a variable is the context within which it is defined. For the most part all PHP variables only have a single scope. This single scope spans included and required files as well.

[Please refer to the PHP Manual to understand the variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Tol solve the issue, change the function signature to

```
function createXMLfile($mysqli, $booksArray)
{ 
    // … rest of code …
}
```

And then pass the variable from the outer scope to the function scope:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "******", "****");
$booksArray = array();    
createXMLfile($mysqli, $booksArray);
```

You can also use a global variable to pull in variables from the global scope:

```
function createXMLfile($booksArray)
{ 
    global $mysqli;
    // … rest of code …    
}
```

[But using global variables is generally discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions/5166527#5166527) because it leads to tightly coupled code and makes the code less easy to reason about.

Comment: Or pass it as argument

Comment: @BNT, i just tried by passing as argument and it worked. Destructive, Thanks for your answer, i am using this way, it worked.. :)